# XM Cloud Content Backup

Tags: xm-cloud

I am looking for a process in the case that content in XM Cloud gets deleted / wiped by mistake.
Is there a point in time restore function available (even if it's only via Sitecore Support)?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this, the only option is via Sitecore Support.

I do know that point-in-time self service functionality is on the roadmap, that would allow you to "snapshot" an environment and later restore that snapshot. But I do not know the timetable for this functionality.

Comment: What kind of backup frequency / window is the Sitecore Support restore option? Per minute / hour / 4 hours?

Comment: I do believe it's a rolling backup. But you would need to double check that in an SLA somewhere before putting a gamble on it :D

Comment: Backup and DR is covered by the SaaS product SLA here: https://www.sitecore.com/legal/sla/saas

Comment: @RichardSeal it's covered in respect to major outages or DR scenarios. But it doesn't cover "oops I deleted this section of the content tree and the recycle bin restore didn't restore everything".